# Infinite Non Abelian Extensions Unramified Outside p

Tags: noncommutative-rings, iwasawa-theory, ramification

Let $K$ be a number field and $p$ be a fixed odd prime. Suppose $\mathfrak{p}\mid p$ is the only prime prime above $p$ in $K$, and that $p$ does not divide the class number of $K$ (I am okay with assuming $K$ has class number 1, if it makes the problem easier). Let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve without complex multiplication and consider the extension $K_\infty=K(E_{p^\infty})$ over $K$.

Under what conditions can one hope to expect that $K_\infty$ is unramified outside $p$.

Comment: The Neron-Ogg-Shafarevich criterion tells you that this occurs if and only if the elliptic curve $E/K$ has good reduction away from $\mathfrak{p}$.